# Find the first instance of a null value in a group as long as no non null comes after - Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to find the very first row where a certain field is null but the caveat is there cannot be a non-null coming after.  If there isn't a null value or a non-null comes after the null then I do not want to return that one at all. I am using Teradata SQL and the following mock dataset should illustrate what I am looking for.

```
ID | Date      | Field_Of_Interest
A  | 1/1/2015  | 1
A  | 2/1/2015  | 1
A  | 3/1/2015  | 
A  | 4/1/2015  | 
A  | 5/1/2015  | 
B  | 1/1/2015  | 1
B  | 2/1/2015  | 1
B  | 3/1/2015  | 
B  | 4/1/2015  | 1
B  | 5/1/2015  | 
C  | 1/1/2015  | 1
C  | 2/1/2015  | 1
C  | 3/1/2015  | 1
C  | 4/1/2015  | 1
C  | 5/1/2015  | 1
D  | 1/1/2015  | 1
D  | 2/1/2015  | 1
D  | 3/1/2015  | 
D  | 4/1/2015  | 
D  | 5/1/2015  | 1
```

Desired Result:

```
ID | Date      
A  | 3/1/2015
B  | 5/1/2015
```

Since C and D have a non-null for the last record I do not want them all all.

Where I run into trouble are situations like B or D where I can't just take the minimum of the date field where Field_Of_Interest is null.  Another thought I had was to find the min where null and the max where not null and if the date for the min was greater than that of the max use that.  The problem there is in B where a non-null came after a null and then it went back to null.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this give you what you want?

```
SELECT
    T1.ID,
    MIN(T1.some_date) AS some_date
FROM
    My_Table T1
WHERE
    T1.some_column IS NULL AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM My_Table T2 WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID AND T2.some_date > T1.some_date AND T2.some_column IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY
    T1.ID
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT
    T1.id,
    MIN(T1.some_date) AS some_date
FROM
    My_Table T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN My_Table T2 ON
    T2.id = T1.id AND
    T2.some_date > T1.some_date AND
    T2.some_column IS NOT NULL
WHERE
    T1.some_column IS NULL AND
    T2.id IS NULL
GROUP BY
    T1.id
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the first one and it works great, I didn't know about NOT EXISTS, that's a new one for me and very helpful.  Thanks again for your help this is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a difference of row number or using subqueries.  The latter method results in a query like this:

```
select id, min(date)
from t
where t.field_of_interest is null and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.date > t.date and
                        t2.field_of_interest is not null
                 )
group by id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I already marked the answer above as correct (it had the same logic and you guys must have answered about the same time) but I gave you an upvote at least.  Thanks again, this was a really great solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the expected result with a single table access using Windowed Aggregate Functions. Depending on the actual data/query this might be more efficient.

```
SELECT ID, MIN(dt)
FROM
 (
   SELECT *
   FROM tab
   QUALIFY
      -- returns NULL until the first row with a value in Field_Of_Interest
      MIN(Field_Of_Interest) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY ID
            ORDER BY dt DESC
            ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) IS NULL
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY 1
```